# Lua Mac os.execute open Terminal and run command

Tags: macos, lua

I need to open the Mac Terminal and run some commands with os.execute in Lua

```
export VAMP_PATH=/path/to/plugin/directory
```

```
cd /path/to/script
```

```
./sonic-annotator -l
```

EDIT: got it to work without terminal with this

```
os.execute('export VAMP_PATH="'..script_path..'sonic/mac64/vamp"; cd "'..script_path..'sonic/mac64/"; ./sonic-annotator -d vamp:qm-vamp-plugins:qm-barbeattracker:beats -w csv "'..filename..'"')
```

Comment: What is your question please? The code doesn't appear to be Lua?

Comment: Why do you want a Terminal? Processes and scripts don't need one unless they output something you need to see. Is that the case?

Comment: Perhaps you want `p=io.popen("/bin/sh","w"); p:write("ls","\n")`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question, you can start a Terminal and run some `bash` commands in it like this:

```
os.execute("osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd /Users/mark && ls\"'")
```

But, as I said in the comments, you don't necessarily need a Terminal to run a script, so you can just run a command like this:

```
os.execute("export V=fred; cd /Users/mark && ./SomeScript.sh")
```

If you are running a script because you just want the user to see the output of the script, it is often easier and involves far less quoting if you run your command and pipe the result to `open -f` like this, which displays the output in a text editor:

```
os.execute("cd /Users/mark; ls | open -f")
```

[image]